# Language selector position on mobile device

Tags: mobile-web, language, mobile-first

I am looking the best position for language selectors on mobile device.

Currently, I place buttons (for french and english languages) in menu only (see attachment)

[image: Menu]

Do you think it is enough or should I place them also on top bar ? If I have to, where would be the best place ?

[image: top bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to provide this option, **because the majority of apps refer to the default language user sets while setting up her/his phone for the first time - the operating system language**. This approach is making a task easier for everyone.

If you still wish to provide that option - I think placing **EN** (or any selected language) alongside the hamburger menu will be better. Use a selectbox component when users tap on it to change.

## For website

**Think of placing it at footer**. The text would read 'Select your language/country: **EN-US**'

Comment: It is a website, not an app. It is why I need this option. I thought about selectbox.

Comment: @Trevize Thanks! The screenshots are appearing as apps

Comment: No problem. If I use selectbox. What language should be displayed : the language currently used or the targeted language. To be more clear : if the page is in english, the selector should display EN or FR ?

Comment: @Trevize The targeted language/languages, because the user is already aware of the default.

Comment: Thanks for that. About your edited comment "for website": are you talking about footer of every single page or only the "menu" page footer ? In every footer page, I think user do not scroll to find a language selector : if they don't understand, they leave.

Comment: @Trevize I agree with your partially to have it on landing page, but imagine a situation where I'm buying something and to have better understanding of the transaction I want to change the language while I'm on **check out** page.

Comment: Yes, ok. On landing page, could be a good option, I will add it. Concerning your context, I agree : it would be useful to change the language at any page. The context of my website is a music festival (only festival and artists presentation, no ticket selling). So I think this option would be not appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The menu should be fine, and another option would be to align it to the left side since there is the X (exit) icon on the right.

Comment: Good idea, maybe a selectbox instead of 2 buttons ?